# name is null error while doing group by column_name in confluent kafka ksql

Tags: group-by, apache-kafka, create-table, ksqldb

I get error in confluent-5.0.0.

`ksql>CREATE TABLE order_per_hour AS SELECT after->order_id,count(*) FROM transaction WINDOW SESSION(60 seconds) GROUP BY after->order_id;`

name is null

error-name is null

after is the struct field in schema.
simple select query without group by is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've submitted a PR to add support for this to KSQL here https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/2076

Hope this helps,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can only use column names in the `GROUP BY` clause. As a work around you can write your query as the following:

`CREATE STREAM foo AS SELECT after->order_id as o_id FROM transaction;`
`CREATE TABLE order_per_hour AS SELECT o_id,count(*) FROM foo WINDOW SESSION(60 seconds) GROUP BY o_id;`